# access ADFS/OIDC protected webapi with curl or python

Tags: python, openid-connect, adfs

I would like to access a webapi by a script(bash or python), which is protected by mod_openidc/apache2 and an self-hosted ADFS.
For the authentication, a certificate from a smartcard or locally stored certificate is required.
I already tried several approaches with python or curl, but got no nearly working script.

approach at python:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
client_id="abcdef-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdefghijk"
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
#client = BackendApplicationClient()

oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
protected_url="https://protectedurl/page/"

oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://sts.myserver.net/adfs/oauth2/token/', include_client_id=True, cert=('/home/user/cert.pem', '/home/user/server.key'))
```

which lead to: "oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientError: (invalid_client) MSIS9627: Received invalid OAuth client credentials request. Client credentials are missing or found empty"

curl:

```
curl --cert /home/user/cert.pem --key /home/user/server.key
https://sts.example.net/adfs/oauth2/authorize/?response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20allatclaims&client_id=XXX&state=XXXredirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.net%2Fpage%2Fredirect_uri&nonceXXX
```

Which gives the sts page in html

So I think I dont have some small bug, but a wrong approach
Since it works in a browser, I dont suggest a issue on server side

Any approaches and examples are warmly welcome